# how do I remove columns from a collection of ndarrays that correspond to zero elements of one of the arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

I have some data in 3 arrays with shapes:

```
docLengths.shape = (10000,)
docIds.shape = (10000,)
docCounts.shape = (68,10000)
```

I want to obtain relative counts and their means and standard deviations for some i:

```
docRelCounts = docCounts/docLengths
relCountMeans = docRelCounts[i,:].mean()
relCountDeviations = docRelCounts[i,:].std()
```

Problem is, some elements of docLengths are zero. This produces NaN elements in docRelCounts and the means and deviations are thus also NaN.

I need to remove the data for documents of zero length. I could write a loop, locating zero length doc's and removing them, but I was hoping for some numpy array magic that would do this more efficiently. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
docRelCounts = docCounts/docLengths

goodDocRelCounts = docRelCounts[i,:][np.invert(np.isnan(docRelCounts[i,:]))]
relCountMeans = goodDocRelCounts.mean()
relCountDeviations = goodDocRelCounts.std()
```

`np.isnan` returns an array of the same shape with `True` where original array is `NaN`, `False` elsewhere. And `np.invert` inverts this and then you get `goodDocRelCounts` with only the values that are not `NaN`.

Comment: Nice(: thanks. I sniffed around and came up with an alternative (though essentially similar) method in the meantime (below...)

Comment: Seems I can't post my alternative yet.. Not to worry, eumiro's is quite fine (:

Answer (score 0):

Use nanmean and nanstd from scipy.stats:

```
from scipy.stats import nanmean, nanstd
```

Comment: great! For my purposes at the moment, it serves to actually remove the data as I've other analyses to do on it, and the zero length data is invalid for what I'm doing. I'll keep nanmean and nanstd in mind though! Thanks (:

Answer (score 0):

In the end I did this (I'd actually worked it out before I saw eumiro's answer - it's a bit simpler, but otherwise not any better, just different, so I thought I'd include it :)

```
goodData = docLengths!=0  # find zero elements
docLen = docLen[goodData]
docCounts = docCounts[:,goodData]

docRelCounts = docCounts/docLen
means = map(lambda x:x.mean(), docRelCounts)
stds = map(lambda x:x.std(), docRelCounts)
```